# why is mockito not called when executing mocked method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

Here is my test:

```
    @Test
    public void myTest() throws Exception {

        String aVenueId = "1.2.3";
        Venue2 aVenue = new Venue2(aVenueId);

        VenuesRepository repository = mock(VenuesRepository.class);
        when(repository.getVenue(anyString())).thenReturn(new VenueThumb(aVenue));

        aMethodWithInnerCallToRepositoryGetVenue();
...
    }
```

However when test runs my real code,

this line returns null (as there is no venue with venueId = "1.2.3"

that's why i used my mock for the first place).

```
public void aMethodWithInnerCallToRepositoryGetVenue(){
...
        IVenue v = repository.getVenue(r.venueId);
..
}
```

Comment: Post a complete test case reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mocked a repository in your method, but this mock repository is assigned to a local variable only. So the code calling `repository.getVenue()` calls it on a different repository instance, and not on the one created by Mockito:

```
aMethodWithInnerCallToRepositoryGetVenue();
```

There's no way this method knows about the local variable initialized just before the method call.

Answer (score 0):

As the user JB Nizet has written you are using two different instances of repository. You can do something like this: first you have a repository class you want to mock being a collaborator in the next class.

```
public class VenuesRepository {

    public IVenue getVenue(String id) {
        return new IVenue() {
            // do something
        };
    }
}
```

Class Foo uses an instance of VenuesRepository as a collaborator which is not the objective of your unit test so you should mock its behavior when required.

```
public class Foo {

    private VenuesRepository repository;

    public Foo(VenuesRepository repo) {
        repository = repo;
    }

    public IVenue getVenueFromRepository(String id) {
        return repository.getVenue(id);
    }
}
```

Now the test

```
public class FooTest {

    @Test
    public void testGetRepositoryWithMock() throws Exception {
        String aVenueId = "1.2.3";

        VenuesRepository repository = mock(VenuesRepository.class);
        when(repository.getVenue(anyString())).thenReturn(mock(IVenue.class));

        Foo foo = new Foo(repository);

        assertNotNull(foo.getVenueFromRepository(aVenueId));
    }
}
```

Now the instance of repository which has been mocked is the same.

I hope it helps.